# Appearance of Menu Items with website loading

Tags: html, css

When you open up the page while it's loading you will see menu coming up, then disappearing. How can I fix that problem. I tried several ways like z-index didn't work out. I don't even have any idea why it's doing that....

Thank you guys..

Website link;
http://goo.gl/uYmiJ

Image that I took to help you see the problem;
http://goo.gl/voCl8

Comment: Do you want the menu to appear horizontally, as it appears in the image? Or should it appear vertically as it is now but over the image?

Comment: it's openning vertical which is what I want.  =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried it with the latest firefox and ie version and it worked fine. Which browser are you using? What code are you using to hide the menu?

Maybe the opacity-property is the problem. You need to use cross-browser-css.

```
opacity: .75; /* Standard: FF gt 1.5, Opera, Safari */
filter: alpha(opacity=75); /* IE lt 8 */
-ms-filter: "alpha(opacity=75)"; /* IE 8 */
-khtml-opacity: .75; /* Safari 1.x */
-moz-opacity: .75; /* FF lt 1.5, Netscape */
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you this helped a lot even though it wasn't what I was asking. What happens is when you first open the website  menu shows up then disappears. Unfortunately it happens in only Google Chrome..

Comment: without seeing the code (as I formerly wrote) I cannot help you any further. Just have a look at all css3 attributes and see that all support cross-browser-css.

Comment: you can see HTML & CSS from the browser what you you need ? I am taking a look at them but still dont have any idea.

Comment: if I use display:none; and display:block; it works fine but it doesnt do the effect.

Comment: hm... thats what I just wanted to let you prove. So I don't know any further I'm afraid.